# Updating a value in SQL (better-sqlite3) with Node.JS

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite, sql-update, better-sqlite3

I currently have a database of people with each individual person and they hold a status value. I am trying to change their status value.

```
  const id = parseInt(req.params.id , 10);
  const { valid, messageObj } = validateId(id);
  if (!valid) {
    res.status(400).send(messageObj);
  }

  let { status, priority } = req.body;
  let people = db.prepare('select * from people').all();
  const person = people.find(person => person.id === id);    

  if(status !== 'none' & status == 'ready' || status == 'done'){
    let updates = db.query(
        'UPDATE people SET ? WHERE ?', 
         [{ status: status }, { id: id }]
    );
  }
```

I keep getting an error of `db.query is not a function` but I get that for every function that I try.

Pretty new to SQL but just trying to figure this out or any documentation that will help me as the better-sqlite3 doesn't have any `update` functions in the official documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I cannot find a function called `query()` in the [better-sqlite3 API for the `Database` class](https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3/blob/master/docs/api.md). I think that you would need to [`prepare()`](https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3/blob/master/docs/api.md#preparestring---statement) a [`Statement` object](https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-statement), then [`run()`](https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3/blob/master/docs/api.md#runbindparameters---object) it.

Also, column names cannot be passed as bound parameters. Your query should look like:

```
UPDATE people SET status = ? WHERE name = ?
```

You would need to change this:

```
let updates = 
    db.query('UPDATE people SET ? WHERE ?', [{ status: status }, { id: id }]);
```

To:

```
const stmt = db.prepare('UPDATE people SET status = ? WHERE id = ?'); 
const updates = stmt.run(status, id);
```

Comment: Condensed `const info = db.prepare('update people set status = ? where id =?').run(status,id);` if you want

Comment: `Also, column names cannot be passed as bound parameters.` It does support bound parameters, see e.g. https://github.com/WiseLibs/better-sqlite3/blob/master/docs/api.md#binding-parameters and the example at https://github.com/WiseLibs/better-sqlite3/blob/master/docs/api.md#binding-parameters -- are you saying that, although they are supported from INSERT, they are not supported in UPDATE statements for some reason?

Comment: `bind-parameter` is part of the `expr` syntax on https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Comment: @ChrisW: yes it support bind parameters to pass *values*, but not other elements such as a column *name* or a table name for example. In the `insert` example that you linked, it is values that are bound. Keep in mind that the database needs to be able to *prepare* the statement using the query string only (not the bind parameters) ; it would not be possible to do if a structural information such as a column name was missing.

Answer (score 0):

According to [templates](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_templates.asp) you can use javascript syntax to replace variables to its value.

```
let updates = db.exec(`UPDATE people SET status='${status}' WHERE id='${id}'`);
```

Comment: This is not safe. This allows SQL Injection. Exec doesn't perform ANY escaping.

Comment: I see, prepare will drop error when code injection try to perform, but you have to handle it far before sql statement. You have to check the value of status variable before use template, and in case of attempt injection you have to refuse, and terminate the procedure before sql, so please separate the safe problems from replace method.